# Closed form for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+1}}}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx$???

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The integral is from WolframAlpha's ad, and I got curious to what the answer actually is.
I tried using the square-square technique, but that leads me to this:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}}}{(x^2+x)\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx$$
I don't even know how to go about this integral in general.

Is there even a closed form for this???

Comment: Even the antiderivative is not too difficult. I give tou you the first step : let $x=\sqrt{\sinh (t)}$ to face $$I=\frac 12 \int  \frac{\sqrt{\coth (t)+1}}{\sqrt{\sinh (t)}+1}\,dt$$

Comment: *Is there even a closed form for this?* Yes, there is a closed form. I posted it for you, but it was deleted.

Comment: This is what I got: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{\sqrt{\sinh(x)}+\sinh(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec(u)\sqrt{\sec(u)}}{(\sqrt{2\sec(u)}+\tan(u))}du$$
I don't see where to go from here.